# NotNull Boolean value If else with Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, conditional-statements

I wrote a single line code to make if else statement. I found it redundantly long. How can I make this line shorter and more efficient? isLocked is a boolean value here.

```
Stream.of( isLocked ).filter( x -> !x ).findFirst().orElseThrow( LimitLockException::new );
```

Comment: what is `isLocked` is it `Boolean isLocked = ..?`

Comment: Yes, isLocked is Boolean value. I had mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using a library class to force this into a one-liner, `Optional` is slightly better suited than `Stream` (which ends up giving you an `Optional` anyway):

```
Boolean isLocked = true;
Optional.of(isLocked).filter(x -> ! x).orElseThrow(LimitLockException::new);
```

I still don’t like it, though. `orElseThrow` is for unexpectedly missing an element, a value that should be present. It’s not for something being locked. For throwing an exception in that case, I suggest that you prefer to have a `throw` statement conspicuously located on its own line. So use the `if` statement from Naman’s answer.

Comment: 1. There is no point in wrapping with `Optional.of(isLocked)` and 2. `orElseThrow` without using a return value is pointless. (you could reverse the condition to use `ifPresent`). That said/changes rethink and restart from point 1.

Comment: @Naman I agree in point 1., and like you I don’t understand why anyone should want this. To me your three-line `if` statement is the good way to go. There may be a wide-spread misconception that terseness of code is a goal. It’s not. Clarity is. Often the two go hand in hand, but not in this case (and if we wanted brevity, your one-line `if` would have beaten everything).

Answer (score 5):

Using streams is overkill here, you seem to be looking for -

```
if (isLocked) {
    throw new LimitLockException();
}
```

In "one-line" =>

```
if (isLocked) throw new LimitLockException();
```

Comment: I want to write it in single line

Comment: So you mean using Stream here is overkill ?

Comment: @gungor this is the short way, what did you mean single line?

Comment: @gungor In fact, that's the message! "Using streams is overkill here certainly".

Comment: @YCF_L I mean writing if else statement without using if else

Comment: @gungor In case you have many verification like this, I would suggest to create a method for example, which return a Boolean or in case is invalid throw an exception, and then call this method in one line

Comment: I don’t like the one-liner in this case. `throw` radically changes the flow of control, so it deserves a prominent place on its own line, IMHO.